# Flutter stream doesn't listen or detect change

Tags: dart, flutter

I have problem, i have 3 dart files,

home.dart contain button with onclick:

```
final cartEmiter = CartEmitter();
cartEmiter.emitCart("add_cart");
```

cart.dart contain:

```html
class CartEmitter {
  StreamController _controller = StreamController.broadcast();
  void emitCart(action) {
    _controller.add(action);
    // print(action);
  }

  Stream get cartAction => _controller.stream;
}
```

and in main.dart I have this code to change the cart badge.

```html
StreamSubscription _cartCountSubscribtion;

int _cartCount = 0;

@override
  void initState() {
    _cartCountSubscribtion = CartEmitter().cartAction.listen((action) {
      print(action);
      setState(() {
         _cartCount++;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cartCountSubscribtion.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

But it doesn't work, no error, no output printed.
Is my code wrong or how to listen to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new `CartEmitter` in the `initState` function, and another one in the onclick code. Those two are not connected in any way, so the event you emit with the `emitCart` call is emitted on a different `CartEmitter` than the one you listen to.

You need to share the same `CartEmitter` instance between the `initState` and `onclick` code.

Alternatively, if you *know* that you will only ever need one `CartEmitter`, you can make the `_controller` static, so the same controller (and stream) is shared between all instances of `CartEmitter`.
In that case, you can make `emitCart` and `cartAction` static too, and never create any `CartEmitter` instance at all.

Comment: so how to use or define same CartEmitter on different file?

Comment: oh done, i define final cartemitter on cart.dart
thanks for your help